# Low side MOSFET switch disconnecting charging

Tags: mosfet, switches, circuit-design, ground

I have a problem with the design of low side MOSFET switch, that would be implemented in my electrical system to disconnect PV panels from a battery. This switch would be controlled by Controlling PCB.

[image]

Unfortunately, I don't know how to do it, my controlling circuit has to be on battery ground potential. How am I supposed to do it? Can I do it as simple as that?:

[image]

I don't think so, because I don't see the return path of the current, that would charge gate capacitance.

Comment: Am I corrent, that application like this would be correct (current would close through parasitic diode?)

Comment: As you drew it, the body diode would block the charging current, but would let the battery discharge through the solar panel (in the dark, say) if nothing else is blocking it.

Comment: That's in situation, when gate is drived low, but while driving it high, the mosfet would conduct, as I deduce.